# Unable to fully close remote SSH tunnel in script's exit

Tags: bash, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm writing a script, which double-hop SSH-forwards port 80 from our remotely deployed VMs, and opens this "status page" in a local browser. To open it, the SSH tunnel must be "backgrounded", however doing so causes the SSH tunnel to exit with a persistent tunnel remaining on the SSH server that I'm tunneling through (`bastion`). Here is the script, so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
# SSH needs a HUP when this script exits
shopt -s huponexit

echo "SSH Forwards the VM status page for a given host..."
read -p "Host Name: " CODE
PORT=$(($RANDOM + 1024))

# "-t -t" (force tty) needed to avoid orphan tunnels on bastion after exit. (Only seems to work when not backgrounded?)
ssh -t -t -4L $PORT:localhost:$PORT user1@bastion sudo ssh -4NL $PORT:localhost:80 root@$CODE.internal-vms &
PID=$!

# Open browser to VM Status Page
sleep 1
open http://localhost:$PORT/

# Runs the SSH tunnel in the background, ensuring it gets killed on shell's exit...
bash

kill -CONT $PID
#kill -QUIT $PID
echo "Killed SSH Tunnel. Exiting..."
sleep 2
```

Unfortunately, given the backgrounding of the SSH tunnel (using `&` on line 10), when the script is killed (via CTRL-C), the "bastion" server ends up having an orphaned SSH connection remaining indefinitely.

The "`-t -t`" and "`shopt -s huponexit`" are fixed I've tried, but don't seem to help. I've also tried various SIG's in the final `kill`. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Regrettably there are a few odd contstraints that I've inherited in this system. The biggest being the need to use sudo to ssh from bastion to the VMs. And there are numerous VMs, so deploying user1's SSH key to all of them would be difficult.

Comment: May I suggest Ansible to manage your VMs and also deploy keys to all of them? It would make your life far easier and the VMs more secure.

Comment: Actually, we're in the process of rolling out Ansible configuration management right now. Ansible is wonderful. Unfortunately there are a ton of legacy services that we'll have to "Ansiblize" bit by bit.

Comment: I"m almost certain I have seen even `-t -t -t` used with some success with SSH, but don't recall the specific problem being addressed. It's worth a try. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The `-f` flag can be used to background the process. To end the connection, `ssh -O exit user1@bastion` is a better option than `kill` which is rather violent.

I would do it like this. Fyi, I didn't test the modified script, although I regularly use a similar, long SSH command.

```
#!/bin/sh
# SSH needs a HUP when this script exits
shopt -s huponexit

echo "SSH Forwards the VM status page for a given host..."
read -p "Host Name: " CODE
PORT=$(($RANDOM + 1024))

# "-t -t" (force tty) needed to avoid orphan tunnels on bastion after exit. (Only seems to work when not backgrounded?)
ssh -t -t -f -4L $PORT:localhost:$PORT user1@bastion sudo ssh -4NL $PORT:localhost:80 root@$CODE.internal-vms
#PID=$!

# Open browser to VM Status Page
sleep 1
open http://localhost:$PORT/

# Runs the SSH tunnel in the background, ensuring it gets killed on shell's exit...
#bash

#kill -CONT $PID
#kill -QUIT $PID
ssh -O exit user@bastion

echo "Killed SSH Tunnel. Exiting..."
sleep 2
```

Comment: I've implemented this recommendation, with a few modifications (ControlPath needs a socket, not a plain file). However, upon disconnect, the second connection invoked by sudo stays running on Bastion, and has to be manually disconnected on that server.

Comment: I think the solution is to avoid using sudo, as it invokes a new shell process, which isn't receiving signals from the originating SSH connection.

Comment: ControlPath is needed for `ssh -O exit` to work. You're likely right on the sudo-ed SSH not exiting because it runs as root. One solution is to make the SSH server auto d/c after a certain timeframe http://www.2daygeek.com/automatically-disconnect-inactive-idle-ssh-sessions/.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to do away with the need for sudo in this process. It's a funky way of doing this sort of thing in any case.